# Se tiene una clase y una lista con tres atributos, se tiene que implementar un método que devuelva otra lista

Tags: python

estoy frente a este problema que lo he intentado resolver de muchas maneras, pero no he llegado a una respuesta. Si alguien me puede ayudar:

Se tiene la clase Nodo con los atributos v y next, una ListaEnlazada con únicamente los atributos prim, ult y len. Implementar el método filtrar() que recibe una función y devuelve otra lista enlazada (nueva) para el cual a cada elemento de la funcion, devuelve TRUE.
Ejemplo:

L = 1 -> 5 -> 8 -> 8 -> 2 -> 8

L.filter(es_primo) -> L2 = 5 -> 2

IMPORTANTE: escribir en la primera sentencia del código la siguiente linea
from ListaEnlazadaTest import *

Por ahora voy por así, como puedo continuar?

```
class Nodo:
    def __init__(self,v=None,next=None):
        self.v = v
        self.next = next

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.v)

class ListaEnlazada:
    def __init__(self):
       self.prim = None
       self.ult = None
       self.len = 0
```

Comment: Por favor agrega lo que lleves al momento, si tienes dudas para formular tu pregunta aquí puedes leer [ask]

Comment: ok ahora lo agrego

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No he entendido muy bien la explicación del ejercicio. Si puedes editar la pregunta te puedo ayudar un poco mejor. Por lo que he entendido necesitas una clase para tratar listas enlazadas o encadenadas. He modificado un poco el programa para que sea un poco más completo. Si necesitas alguna modificación no dudes en hacermelo saber. Si algún compañero con más experiencia puede hacerlo más óptimo que me lo haga saber para poder mejorar yo también. Gracias

```
class LinkedList:
    class Node:
        def __init__(self, value, next_node = None):
            self.value = value
            self.next_node = next_node

    def __init__(self):
        self.__first = None    
        self.__last = None
        self.__len = 0

    def __len__(self):
        return self.__len

    def insert(self, where, value):
        if where < 0 or where > len(self):
            raise IndexError
        else:
            if where == 0:
                self.__first = self.Node(value, self.__first)
            elif where == len(self):
                new_node = self.Node(value)
                self.__last.next_node = new_node
                self.__last = new_node
            else:
                current = self.__first
                current_pos = 1

                while current_pos < where:
                    current = current.next_node
                    current_pos += 1

                current.next_node = self.Node(value, current.next_node)

            self.__len += 1

    def __iter__(self):
        self.__current = self.__first
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.__current != None:
            result = self.__current.value
            self.__current = self.__current.next_node
            return result
        else:
            raise StopIteration

    # Método filtrar

    def filtrar(self, valor):
       """Vas iterando cada uno de los elementos y retornas el booleano"""
       for value in self:
           return True
```

Puedes probar el método con la forma:

```
from ListaEnlazadaTest import *
import random

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_list = LinkedList()
    data1 = [random.randint(10, 15) for i in range(10)]
    data2 = [random.randint(10, 20) for i in range(10)]
    indexs = [0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 4, 3, 4, 6, 2]

    for index, value in zip(indexs, data1):
        my_list.insert(index, value)

    print(data1)

    for e in data2:
        print(e, my_list.filtrar(e))
```

Comment: gracias me has ayudado a resolverlo

Comment: Nada, cualquier duda aquí estamos